# Why did Michael tell Julianne, his best friend, about his wedding on such a short notice?

Tags: plot-explanation, my-best-friends-wedding

In [*My Best Friend's Wedding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Best_Friend%27s_Wedding), the main character, Julianne Potter (played by Julia Roberts) is told by her best friend, Michael, that he is getting married in 4 days.

This doesn't make sense to my wife and me since they are supposed to be best friends. Who tells their best friend about getting married on such a short notice?

I mean, you usually send wedding invitations weeks in advance, so people that are supposedly much less close to Michael must have known about the wedding long before Julianne, his "best friend".

Your "best friend" should be one of the first people to hear about you getting married.

I know that the USA is a large country, and they probably live far from each other at the time before the wedding (I don't remember where they live), and they had fewer means of instant communications 20 years ago (mobile phones were less common, and there were no Facebook, Whatsapp, etc...), but they had landline phones, as well as emails.

Is it explained anywhere in the film? Or was it explained somewhere off-screen (perhaps in some interview with the director or actors)?

Comment: Either he don't want her to stop the wedding or to diminish their deadline *agreement that if neither of them were married by the time they turned 28, they would marry each other*

Comment: @user7294900 If he was afraid she would try to stop the wedding, why tell her at all? I realize there would be no movie if he didn't tell her at all, but it would make more sense (of course they would probably stop being friends if he did that, but telling your supposed best friend such an important thing on such a short notice can also hurt her feelings and damage the friendship).

Comment: I didn't see the movie, but I think it's *unvitation* as in Seinfeld https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Betrayal

Comment: @user7294900 I don't think you send an unvitation to your "best friend". You send an unvitation to someone you don't like (and don't want them to come), when you feel obliged to send it to them.

Comment: I don't think it's that deep... It might be just a plot device to make the movie happen, check https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GreenEyedEpiphany

Answer (score 2):

Considering Kimmy is only 20, I have to assume they haven’t been dating for long, let alone engaged for more than a few months. That being said, in the beginning of the movie when Jules gets ahold of Michael on the phone, he tells her he’s been trying to reach her for a month, implying he tried to tell her before the week of, but she didn’t answer his calls

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  Doesn't it seem weird, though, that he didn't at least send her a note when the invitations went out, so that she didn't find out from someone else?

Comment: It seems plausible that he wanted to tell her by phone or face to face rather than a more impersonal letter. People often consider the way news is delivered to be important.